# How can I smooth my polygons in a Three.js scene?

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, three.js, modeling

I've this model here in Three.js:

[Unsmoothed part of the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXqnI.png)

I used a plug-in from the Unity asset store, to export the model into a JSON file, then imported in my three.js application. The problem is that the plugin doesn't export the smoothing groups, so the quality of the model doesn't look so good.

Is there any way to smooth everything with three.js?

Comment: I have to say, you're really knocking yourself out using "three.js" with Unity.  It would be like having Photoshop at your disposal, but then using ascii art to represent something  :)

Comment: I'll try to be more specific.
I've a JSON file where I've stuff like this:

`"geometries": [
  {
   "uuid": "6b3626f9-548b-4637-b969-4aef3a4200e5", 
   "type": "Geometry", 
   "data": {
    "vertices": *lotsofverts*
    "normals": *lotsofverts*
    "uvs": *lotsofverts*
    "faces": *lotsofverts*
   }
  },}
`

And then I've my html file where I simply load the mesh from the json file.

`loader.load(scenes[sceneName].url + '?v1_1', function (obj) {
      mesh = obj;
      scene.add(mesh); }`

Comment: Try this: modifier.modify( mesh.geometry ); and then add to scene

Comment: @iMatrix7 Did you try `mesh.geometry.computeVertexNormals()`? That may work if vertices are shared.

Comment: Yes, tried both methods, the application doesn't start at all if I try to insert those lines (also once at time ofc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the THREE.SubdivisionModifier and use it like this:

```
var modifier = new THREE.SubdivisionModifier(divisions);

// Apply the modifier to your geometry NOT MESH.
modifier.modify( geometry );
```

Actually it's not included in Three.js build, so you have to import it.
You can get it [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/modifiers/SubdivisionModifier.js)

**UPDATE 1**
Basically you JSON file gets loaded as an Object3d, which is like a container. It's structured like this:

- Object3D
- children (arrays containing your meshes (the number can change based on the model in your scene))

  - Mesh (containing data about your geometry, which is what you need to modify).

So in order to modify the "geometry" you need to access it like so:

```
modifier.modify( mesh.children[0].children[0].geometry );
```

You'll need to apply a modifier to every model in your scene, so:

```
modifier.modify( mesh.children[0].children[0].geometry );
modifier.modify( mesh.children[0].children[1].geometry );
modifier.modify( mesh.children[0].children[2].geometry );
```

depending on the number of models you have. 
It's like you have to open a container and inside you find a smaller container, then another one and so on, until you access geometry data. Hope it is clear enough :)

Comment: @iMatrix7 as you see your JSON type is "Geometry". You don't need a var called Geometry, you need a var of "type" geometry. You can replace what I've called "geometry" with the var containing your json

Comment: I think what **iMatrix7** wants is a some kind of *smooth shading*, not subdivision.

Comment: If I put just the first line `var modifier = new THREE.SubdivisionModifier(divisions);` the application doesn't start anymore.

Comment: @leota ReferenceError: divisions is not defined

Comment: @iMatrix7 you need to replace "divisions" with an integer value. That value says how many times faces will be divided. So it will be like: var modifier = new THREE.SubdivisionModifier(2); Don't set it too high otherwise your model will be very heavy

Comment: @leota Thanks, it works now, but I still got the problem of the "geometry" var. I tried, as you suggested, the line `modifier.modify( mesh.geometry )` but I got the error: "geometry is undefined". And no idea where to apply.. since I just import the file as an OBJ, and then assign it to the mesh var. Oh gosh..

Comment: @iMatrix7 could you please do a: console.log(mesh) and write the output,so I can see what's in that mesh. Maybe it has been loaded as a BufferGeometry, I'm not sure

Comment: @leota Object { uuid: "e1e77a9e-3869-476b-bc85-6e8675c24468", name: "World", type: "Object3D", parent: Object, children: Array[121], up: Object, [...]

Comment: @iMatrix7 could you please post part of the code, just editing your initial question, or even better you can create a JSFiddle so I can replicate it and better see what's going on

Comment: @leota Here we go. "jsfiddle.net/hyvd4s2a"

Comment: @leota Wow, you have no idea what a mess I've to do now to smooth each model, but hey, you got it! It works great! Thank you so much!! :)

Comment: @iMatrix7 Good luck :)